# Application creation failed

Tags: facebook

I create facebook application and receive this message:

App creation failed
You've been blocked from creating apps because we haven't been able to verify your account. You need to use your real name to maintain an account on Facebook, but you can set up a separate test account for your apps. Learn more: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

If you believe you have received this message in error, please submit an appeal: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=140703502680919.

Does anyone of you receive this message when creating app ?

Thank you,
Regards,
Hai

Comment: I'm having this problem too, just trying to create an App on Facebook and I'm being denied. I've added my phone number, verified it and even added my credit card details but it still won't work, ridiculous. Perhaps it's not working properly at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

send them a copy of your ID (you can erase the numbers) i did it after receiving the mail below and i could make apps again

mail from fb after blocking:
In an effort to maintain a culture of authenticity on the site, Facebook requires users to provide their real first and last names. Impersonating anyone or anything is prohibited, and fake accounts are a violation of our Statement of Rights and Responsibilities.

Our systems indicated that your account may not be authentic based on a variety of factors. If you believe you are being prevented from creating apps by mistake, please reply to this email with a digital image of your government-issued identification. Make sure the identification you provide meets all of the following requirements:

- Must be government-issued (e.g. passport, driver's license)
- Must be in color
- Must clearly show your full name, date of birth, and photo

If possible, please save this file in JPEG image format.

You may black out any personal information that is not needed to verify your identity (e.g., address, license number). Rest assured that we will permanently delete your ID from our servers once we have used it to verify the authenticity of your account.

Note that writing in and submitting your ID multiple times will not result in a faster response. Once you submit your initial request, it is placed in a queue and responded to accordingly. We appreciate your patience and apologize for any inconvenience this may cause while we're investigating the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: did sending photo of an id solved your problem if so how many days did it take?

Answer (score 0):

Either you have a test user that is creating the application or your account does not have a cell phone number attached to it.

I have seen this error and it had to do with adding a cell phone number to my account.

Comment: I added and verified my cell phone but I still cannot create app.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I was able to solve the problem by:

Turning off certain security features temporarily (login approvals and always browsing on a secure connection)
Removing both my credit card and all mobile phone numbers from my account using settings.

I then tried to create another app. When I got the error message, I used the link to validate my cell phone, which re-added it to my account. Creating the app once again finally worked.

I hope this works for you!